# Array is null, why does PHP not warn about this?

Tags: php

I stumbled across this irritating behaviour of my PHP-Installation:

```
$myArray = null;  
$myValue = $myArray['some_index']; // <--- this does not even throw a notice!!
```

I have error_reporting on E_ALL, no error_handler in place.
Did I misconfigure anything?

Trying this:

```
$myArray = array();
$myValue = $myArray['some_index']; // <--- does throw notice as expected.
```

What am I missing? Trying to access null as an array should at least thow a notice?

Comment: I will probably get downvoted for this one...

Comment: 11 hours too late today :)